# Why would OAuth be used with no third party?

Tags: rest, security, oauth

I've been handed a working system that needs changes, and there's something about it that doesn't make sense to me. I'm hoping that maybe someone here could explain it to me.

My client has a web app that talks to a SaaS via a REST API, to get certain information. That REST API has an OAuth 1 authentication. Our system has the account ID and password (they actually call it a token but I think it's basically a password.) Our system calculates a bunch of different tokens according to the OAuth protocol, like `oauth_consumer_key`, `oauth_nonce` etc. Then it uses these tokens to authenticate when it's making the request.

What puzzles me is this: As far as I know, this complex OAuth flow is supposed to be three-legged. e.g. if a person wants to tell Facebook that he allows web app Foo to access their information on Facebook, they first do the OAuth step with Facebook and then send the tokens to Foo. This is crucial because Foo can't be trusted with the user's Facebook password.

But what's the logic of doing an OAuth dance when there are only 2 parties? Are there any advantages to this over just sending the password on every request? (which is of course encrypted.) Or maybe this is a case of cargo cult by that SaaS's developers?

P.S. I checked out the official SDK provided by the SaaS company. They do the same logic in their SDK.